# Force the use of an alternate POM file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

In my maven project I usually use the POM file named *pom.xml*. I have a second POM file though (call it *pom_alt.xml*), which I occasionally use to perform a very different build of the same project. To do so I specify the `-f` option in the command line

```
mvn clean package -fpom_alt.xml
```

as suggested by `man mvn`:

```
   -f,--file
          Force the use of an alternate POM file.
```

Now, when I am coding in eclipse I usually need maven to use *pom.xml*, but sometimes I should code or debug while the other file *pom_alt.xml* is used instead. Is there a way to tell the eclipse maven integration to use that file? Currently I am temporarily copy-pasting from *pom_alt.xml* to *pom.xml* since I seldom happen to need that, but you can see that's not optimal.

I am with Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, Mars Release 4.5.0.

**UPDATE**

I could build from the command line or use *Run As Maven build* as in
[Carlos Andres' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37286742/2754507), but ideally I would like to define a persistent setting, like a property or preference. This because I find nice if the POM file can be fixed while I am doing things like running as Java Application and test cases, or executing on a server. Processes that require a project clean or server restart are often triggering a maven build with the default POM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that **M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse** is installed on Eclipse. Once that is installed go to the project and press right click
[image]

Next, put the command that you want to execute

[image]

This option allow you to save the commands, and the next time all your commands will be saved.

To execute the command recorded go to 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Ideally I would look for a persistent setting: I updated the question to reflect that but I will accept this if no better solution can be found